# concat object property with it's parent property

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, where each object has an array of children, inside this array of children I have other objects which also have an array of children and so on, as following :

```
[
      {
        "id": "10036",
        "text": "A",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "10020",
            "text": "B",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "10030",
                "text": "C",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "id": "10034",
                "text": "D",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "10034",
            "text": "D",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": "10026",
            "text": "E",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "10024",
        "text": "F",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "10020",
            "text": "B",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "10030",
                "text": "C",
                "children": []
              },
              {
                "id": "10034",
                "text": "D",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "10032",
            "text": "G,
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

So for each object in the children array, I want to concat it's id property with it's parent id property, so the result should be like this :

```
[
      {
        "id": "10036",
        "text": "A",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "10036_10020",
            "text": "B",
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "10036_10020_10030",
                "text": "C",
                "children": []
              },
...
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: There are not a particular Javascript way to do this. So you need to implement a simple recursive function read your data and to concatenate your ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this recursive approach

```
function process(arr, parentId)
{        
    parentId = parentId ? "_" + parentId : ""; //if parentId is passed then prefix the delimiter _ with it
    return (arr || []).map( function(item){
       item.id += parentId; //append the parentId
       item.children = process( item.children, item.id ); //invoke the method if the children are there
       return item;
    })
}
process(arr);
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr = [{
    "id": "10036",
    "text": "A",
    "children": [{
        "id": "10020",
        "text": "B",
        "children": [{
            "id": "10030",
            "text": "C",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": "10034",
            "text": "D",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "10034",
        "text": "D",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": "10026",
        "text": "E",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "10024",
    "text": "F",
    "children": [{
        "id": "10020",
        "text": "B",
        "children": [{
            "id": "10030",
            "text": "C",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "id": "10034",
            "text": "D",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "10032",
        "text": "G",
        "children": []
      }
    ]
  }
];

function process(arr, parentId) {
  parentId = parentId ? "_" + parentId : "";
  return (arr || []).map(function(item) {
    item.id += parentId; //append the parentId
    item.children = process(item.children, item.id); //invoke the method if the children are there
    return item;
  })
}
console.log(process(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#forEach` to update the `id` value.

```js
var data = [ { "id": "10036", "text": "A", "children": [ { "id": "10020", "text": "B", "children": [ { "id": "10030", "text": "C", "children": [] }, { "id": "10034", "text": "D", "children": [] } ] }, { "id": "10034", "text": "D", "children": [] }, { "id": "10026","text": "E", "children": [] } ] }, { "id": "10024", "text": "F", "children": [ { "id": "10020", "text": "B", "children": [ { "id": "10030", "text": "C", "children": [] }, { "id": "10034", "text": "D", "children": [] } ] }, { "id": "10032", "text": "G", "children": [] } ] } ];

var addParentId = (arr, id = '') => {
  arr.forEach(o => {
    if(id)
      o.id = id + '_' + o.id;
    if(o.children && o.children.length)
      addParentId(o.children, o.id);
  });
}
addParentId(data)
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      function AddIDToChild(obj , prefix)
      {
          if(!obj.length)
              return []

          obj.forEach(function(x) {
              x.id = prefix + x.id
              tmpPrefix = x.id + "-"
              AddIDToChild(x.children , tmpPrefix)


          })


         return obj

      }




      AddIDToChild(q,"")
```

lets think your object name is `q` call this function and answer is what u need

Answer (score 0):

to do what you want you need to use a recursive function ( https://www.sitepoint.com/recursion-functional-javascript/), check the snippet example please.

```js
var array = [
    {
        "id": "10036",
        "text": "A",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "10020",
                "text": "B",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "10030",
                        "text": "C",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "10034",
                        "text": "D",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "10034",
                "text": "D",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "id": "10026",
                "text": "E",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "10024",
        "text": "F",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": "10020",
                "text": "B",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": "10030",
                        "text": "C",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "10034",
                        "text": "D",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "10032",
                "text": "G",
                "children": []
            }
        ]
    }
];

const concatId = (items) => {
    for(var i in items)
        concatIdRecursive(items[i]);
};

const concatIdRecursive = (item) => {
    if (item.hasOwnProperty('children')) {

        for (var i in item.children) {
            var child = item.children[i];

            if (child){
                child.id = item.id + "_" + child.id;
                concatIdRecursive(child);
            }
        }
    }
};
concatId(array);

alert(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Hope you help.